# Safety in using ASP.net MVC to handle POST from Drupal

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, web-services, security, drupal

Just wanted some input from fellow developers on a situation/experiment that we're trying with a project that another developer and myself are working on.

We have a publicly facing Drupal based website that will contain a new form we are adding. However, we want the submitted data to be stored on one of our SQL Server databases. We're just trying different solutions at this point, but one that we're experimenting with is having the Drupal form POST to an MVC application/controller on a different server. Note though that the form itself isn't posting directly to MVC, but rather the posted information is handled server side in a Drupal/PHP module, which then does a second post through our internal network.

As far as we can tell, it works like a charm. We're going to do some request validation (only allowing specific IP addresses/servers to post to the MVC app), as well as SSL tunnelling from MVC to SQL (maybe from PHP to MVC as well).  But I want to make sure I'm not missing anything else. Has anyone else done something similar?  We have other alternatives to fall back on (ASP.net Web Services, SOAP, JSON, etc.), but we thought this would provide an interesting experiment, not to mention the ease it was to setup and have the two systems communicating with one another. But if it's not secure enough, we won't be able to use it.

Comment: Why don't you handle the post directly in the Drupal module? Also, I don't see how you are gaining any security by restricting access to the ASP MVC server...won't the Drupal module act as a gateway and allow public IPs to post to it?

Comment: We're trying to hide the post itself, as the ASP.net MVC controller will not be public facing. By posting server-side (from Drupal/PHP to MVC, instead of HTML form), we're hoping this will hide everything from the client. The HTML form will say it's posting to itself, when in fact a 2nd post is done server-side which is then sent to MVC. The MVC application will have a firewall in between which is only going to allow connections between the Drupal app and MVC.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to secure. You only let the Drupal server connect, but all the Drupal server does is forward the post so basically anyone can post to the Drupal server and indirectly post to your Asp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a pure B2B security perspective, it seems it pretty solid. You've got a firewall limiting incoming connections to a specific IP so short of IP spoofing, the attack sources are pretty limited.

Your MVC app has got a secure SSL based tunnel to the DB so that part of the transport layer looks good, but as you say, the PHP to MVC part could do with some TLS as well.

The one standout omission is that I don't see any authentication between the PHP and MVC apps. The above measures are good, but some further assurance of identity of the incoming request would be nice.

The only other general observation is that I'd be inclined to pursue the web service based avenue as you described earlier. Just posting data directly to an MVC page when it's a purse app to app process isn't ideal. You can certainly make it work as a pure post request, but I'd be inclined to make it a WCF project instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. We're going to abandon the POST request and try a more traditional Web Service/WCF approach, the POST method wasn't working quite as expected (it was posting fine, but we might end up using this somewhere else at a later time so using a web service seemed to be more flexible down the road.)